# why can't I use my android studio 2.3 Instant run features?

Tags: android, android-studio, instant-run

My AS is 2.3 official version

[image]

and I already open the Instan run on the settings 
[image]

but it can't use,and the lightning symbol is always not light,just like this
[image]

I don't why this is,who has other ideas?

Comment: Which API version are you running your project on? When compiling check which API version it is.

Comment: my ` compileSdkVersion 23` and `targetSdkVersion 23`,and I compile my project  on 6.0 , the instant run features works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Android Gradle plugin is version 2.3.0 and Gradle is version 3.3.

Else it wont work. Android studio should tell you that by default. Normally when you open your project or after a clean build.

Comment: I update my as to 2.3.1 and as tell me to update the gradle plugin to 2.3.1 and gradle is 3.3,but the instant run always won't work